# jQuery Mobile, Disable slider issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, frontend

I am working with jQuery Mobile 1.4.3 and I got an issue with the disabled property. When I change the property `disabled` to `false`, the slider doesn't change.

```
 $("#obj").prop("disabled",false);
```

Any suggestion about how can I fix this? Maybe changing some part of the jQueryMobile.js or something?. Note that if you disable jQuery Mobile in the fiddle, it works fine.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/madroneropaulo/AUDtj/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the jQuery Mobile slider you can use the native methods.

```
$("#first").click(function () {
    $("#slider-1").slider('disable');
});
$("#second").click(function () {
    $("#slider-1").slider('enable');
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AUDtj/4/) example.

More information can be found here: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/forms/slider/methods.html

Answer (score 0):

The attribute disabled is active when it is present.  Setting it to false does nothing, setting it to true does nothing.  So to do this you would need to remove the attribute.

```
$("#obj").removeAttr('disabled');
```

and to disable again run,

```
$("#obj").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: I have tried, but when I want to enable it again, it doesn't work.

Comment: when you want to disable the attribute again run `$("#obj").attr('disabled', 'disabled');`

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code to this:

```
$("#first").click(function(){
        $("#Transp").slider("disable");      
 });
$("#second").click(function(){
      $("#Transp").slider("enable");                   
});
```

Working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/AUDtj/5/